# Android view setBackgroundColor() and night mode

Tags: android, themes, android-linearlayout, background-color, android-night-mode

I'm developing an android app and i need to allow user to choose via color picker the list view items's background color. Each listview item is a LinearLayout and i set the background color inside my adapter in this way:

```
holder.rowLayout.setBackgroundColor(this.backgroundColor!!)
```

All works perfectly in day mode but when the app switches to night mode i'm experiencing problems with colors.

Let's take this example:
in day mode i choose bright green background and it correctly applies to the list:

[image]

But when i switch to night mode, colors are the following:

[image]

Now, i don't want to disable day\night to all the application.
I've all my themes responsive to day\night preference, i just want to avoid dark mode to alter colors of this listview only since it's the user that choose its background color and i don't want Android to alter it.

I've tried to apply older themes to the linear layout and using *LinearLayoutCompat* without luck.
Is there somebody that can help me?

Answer (score -1):

try this, on the XML code object input that line:

```
android:forceDarkAllowed="false"
```